# UITableViewController filling cells of different sections with Values

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I'm sure this question is asked before but I couldn't find a solution for it. 
I have a `UITableViewController` with static `cells`, I have 4 `sections` (so far) and each `section` only has 1 `cell`.

this is a part of the first Cell of First section

[image]

and this is the corresponding TableViewCell file,

> AllgemeineProduktdatenCell.swift

```
class AllgemeineProduktdatenCell: UITableViewCell{

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var AngebotsnameTextF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Referenznummer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var modelTextF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bemerkungTextF: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var extrasTextF: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ursprLadenPreisEuroTextF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ursprLadenPreisCentTextF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AngebotsPreisEuroTextF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AngebotsPreisCentTextF: UITextField!

    // Bereich Möbel
    @IBOutlet weak var bereichMoebelLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bereichMoebelPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBAction func showHideBereichMoebelPicker(_ sender: Any) {
        if bereichMoebelPicker.isHidden{
            bereichMoebelPicker.isHidden = false
        } else{
            bereichMoebelPicker.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    // Hersteller
    @IBOutlet weak var chosenHerstellerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var herstellerPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBAction func showHideHerstellerPicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if herstellerPickerView.isHidden{
            herstellerPickerView.isHidden = false
        } else{
            herstellerPickerView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    // Anzeigen auch auf eigener Webseite
    @IBOutlet weak var anzeigenAuchAufEigenerWebseiteSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBAction func anzeigenAufWebsiteSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    // Start des Angebot
    @IBOutlet weak var startDesAngebotChosenDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startDesAngebotDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func hideShowStartDesAngebotDP(_ sender: Any) {
        if startDesAngebotDatePicker.isHidden{
            startDesAngebotDatePicker.isHidden = false
        } else{
            startDesAngebotDatePicker.isHidden = true
        }
    }



    func setUpAllgemeineFields(product: ItemsClass){
        AngebotsnameTextF.text = "ABED"//product.title
        Referenznummer.text = product.artikel_nummer
        modelTextF.text = product.typ_kategorie
    }

}
```

Imagine that I have similar files for each of my cells.

and this is my main View file:

> AddEditVC.swift

```
class AddEditVC: UITableViewController {

    var product_obj: ItemsClass!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllgemeineProduktdaten") as? AllgemeineProduktdatenCell{
            cell.setUpAllgemeineFields(product: product_obj)
            return cell
        } else{
            print("FFFFFFAAAAAILD")
            return AllgemeineProduktdatenCell()
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this application the cell is blank and I even cannot see my `View`s but when I comment out the `cellForRowAt` function then I can see my `outlets` but the fields are empty.

How can I fill the fields of my cell with my object? how should I specify that which cell to be filled (I need it also for my other cells of other sections)

UPDATE:
this is an overview of my `TableViewController`

[image]

Thank you in advance and sorry for such a long question

Comment: Is the `if` statement reached? You might also want to check `indexPath.section` to know which section you are generating the cell for and create the cell accordingly.

Comment: @DávidPásztor no I go directly to the `else` statement, I also tried putting the code in `if indexPath.section == 0` but still it is blank.

Comment: Are you sure you have set up the cell classes and reuse identifiers correctly in `Storyboard`? You should also try printing `indexPath.section` inside `cellForRowAt` and check if you can conditionally cast the cell to its corresponding class.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Should I set `resuseIdentifiers` for all my cells? I just set it for the first one that I'm using now. And also I only have set one class yet. Do I need to do the same for all Cells?
Could you please show with some codes?

Comment: If you have several prototype cells, you need to set both the reuse identifier and class for all of them separately. Do you have several prototypes or you use the same one for all 4 sections?

Comment: @DávidPásztor
I have different cells (I don't understand prototype in this case to be honest) but each cell has a different fields

Comment: In `Storyboard` did you add several different cells to your `UITableView` or just one? When you add a new cell in `Storyboard`, those are called prototype cells. If you have several of them, set up the reuse identifier and class for each of them in `Storyboard` and I will post code for handling them.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I've updated my question with a screenshot. I am making different Classes for my cells and will set up identifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by asking another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791283/collapsible-input-form-swift-3) with the help of [André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051118/andr%C3%A9-slotta), I used a Vertical `UIStackView` and added a button in first row (and whatever element in the as other rows), then add an `IBAction` to the code for the `UIButton` as follow:

```
@IBAction func Section1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let stackView = (sender as AnyObject).superview as? UIStackView else { return }
    guard stackView.arrangedSubviews.count > 1 else { return }
    let sectionIsCollapsed = stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        for i in 1..<stackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
            stackView.arrangedSubviews[i].isHidden = !sectionIsCollapsed
        }
    }
}
```

This will make the `StackView` to collapse, no need to go through complexity of `TableView`s

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up all prototype cell classes and reuse identifiers, you can use below code to generate the cells. Since you didn't include the exact code for your classes, this is just a skeleton code, but you should be able to fill in the gaps.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AllgemeineProduktdaten") as! AllgemeineProduktdatenCell
        cell.setUpAllgemeineFields(product: product_obj)
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OtherCellReuseIdentifier") as! OtherCellClass
        //set up cell content
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the code runs with no errors but the cell is white, I don't see no elements, do I need to also specify that only the first cell? something like indexPath.row == 0 or so?

Comment: No, the switch statement handles that for you if you set it up right. Put print statement into each case and check if they are actually reached. If not, double check that you set up everything in `Storyboard correctly`.

Comment: So I am so close to it but still not working, when I used `let cell = blabla as! ClassCell` it was crashing because of `unwrapping optional value`. then I tried  `if let cell = blabla as? ClassCell` and in `else` statement `return ClassCell`. By printing I realised only the `else` statement is called in each `section`. any ideas why the `if` part doesn't work? all the identifiers are set up.

Comment: It seems like your identifiers are not set up correctly, otherwise cell wouldn't be `nil`. Are you sure you set up the `identifier` and not the `restorationID`? See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k66nF.png) picture for what you need to set up.

Comment: I double checked, I copy pasted all of them to make sure I enter correctly, could it be that it has something to do with using UITableViewController and not a UITableView? or of its settings in Attribute inspector?

Comment: Are you sure it is not because I'm using only one cell?
I have uploaded my whole project to github, could you please check it? here's [my github's link](https://github.com/abednaseri/pw)

Comment: Looking at your project, for a start, you have conflicting Autolayout constraints. Other than that I would create a completely new ViewController and I would add the TableView cells one by one, without adding the sections in `Storyboard` to see if it works that way. But first you should definitely fix your Autolayout constraints.

Comment: Thank you, just to make sure I do it correctly, by 'ViewController' do you mean TableViewController? (Because I must do it in a TableViewController so that I can make the sections collapsible in future.

Comment: Yes, use a `UITableViewController`. FYI you can add a `UITableView` to any `UIViewController`, but if you only need to show a table, a `UITableViewController` is the best choice, since it handles a few things automatically that you would handle yourself manually when adding a tableview to a `UIViewController`.