# Collapsible input form Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am really getting disappointed that's why I ask this question, I found tutorials online for Collapsible TableView but they are with populating the cells with an array of Strings or something similar.

I want to make an Accordion like this with `Swift 3`,

[image]

for some days already I tried a lot of things with `UITableViewController` because apparently that's the only thing you can make collapsible if you want different cells.

Anyway I started to do it but as I asked [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690979/uitableviewcontroller-filling-cells-of-different-sections-with-values/) I cannot show different `UI`s in each `Cell` of each `Section`.

I am sure there's a way to do it, anyone has any suggestions how to make this work?

I thought maybe there's another way to do it (e.g. with `ScrollView` or something)

Comment: Did you try `UIStackView`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta
No I never used it, I will google it now

Comment: @AndréSlotta I have used them actually before, but the only usage I know from them is putting some UIs in one single UI to make it easy to make constraints or so. But how can it help me to make the above thing?

Comment: You could put a `UIButton` as the first element of a vertical `UIStackView` (to expand / collapse a section) and set the `hidden` property for the remaining elements on click.

Comment: @AbedNaseri you could use Tableview with different cell for each section and achieve the same. I have used tableView to achieve an expandable/collapsible tableview with 5 sections and each section having different UI. But it will be very difficult to manage looking into your design but it's definitely possible.

Comment: @AravindAR Look doesn't matter for me now, can you show with some codes? I can't really do it anymore, I'm confused. Have you checked my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690979/uitableviewcontroller-filling-cells-of-different-sections-with-values)? I even have uploaded [my Project](https://github.com/abednaseri/pw) to figure my error but couldn't get any help.

Comment: @AbedNaseri I will look into that and will update you soon.

Comment: @AravindAR Ok thank you

Comment: @Abed Naseri this link will solve your problem and give you an idea of what to do -: https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/. This is not in swift3 but you can definitely find one on stack, i have complete solution posted on stack -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818004/making-table-view-section-expand-swift/43818310#43818310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could implement it with `UIStackView`:

1. Add a vertical `UIStackView` via storyboard
2. Add a `UIButton` as the first subview within the `UIStackView`
3. Add some `UILabel`s as the second, third... subview within the `UIStackView`
4. Add an `IBAction` for the `UIButton` (the first subview)

Implement the `IBAction` like this:

```
@IBAction func sectionHeaderTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let stackView = sender.superview as? UIStackView else { return }
    guard stackView.arrangedSubviews.count > 1 else { return }
    let sectionIsCollapsed = stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].hidden

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) { 
        for i in 1..<stackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
            stackView.arrangedSubviews[i].hidden = !sectionIsCollapsed
        }
    }
}
```

Create multiple `UIStackView`s like this (you can always use the same `IBAction` for the `UIButton`) and embed all of them in a parent (vertical) `UIStackView` to create a view like in your screenshot.

Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Very interesting way of doing it, I really liked it because I don't need to go through that complexity of TableViews and cells. Thank you a lot.
just a small question: I have about 10 of these StackViews, what is the best thing to use? ScrollView? if yes, could you please say how to do it if you know?

Comment: With `UITableView` it's actually very easy too. With `UITableViewController` this has some nice pros, e.g. automatic handling of keyboard.

Comment: @AbedNaseri Yes, a `UIScrollView` is the way to go then. Just embed your outer (parent) `UIStackView` into a `UIScrollView` and set up the specific constraints.